# How to install backtrack 5 onto a USB that doesn't mount with existing OS

Tags: linux, software-installation, usb, backtrack

Here's the specs.

Sandisk Cruzer 4GB USB 2.0

Existing OS: Windows XP Professional SP3

Hardware:

Intel Pentinium 4 Xeon Class (x86 F15 M2 S4) [1.8Ghz]

IBM Thinkpad T-Series T30

So what I am wanting to do is, put backtrack onto the usb and run it like the usb was a hard drive. This way it doesn't affect the physical machine and doesn't erase the current OS. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Try this: http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/UNetbootin_USB_Installer

Comment: Please let us know if you got the info you needed, and if so please select the best answer so the question doesn't remain "unanswered" otherwise let us know if you need any other help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this has been done many times.

To make a Backtrack live-USB, you can use UNetBootin and follow steps similar as these: http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/UNetbootin_USB_Installer

Otherwise if you want it persistent (you have to have a flash drive larger than 4GB), follow these steps: http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Persistent_USB

And you can do all of this in VirtualBox or the LiveCD.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to http://www.backtrack-linux.org/downloads/ and download BT5R3-GNOME-VM-32.7z. Extract archive to a USB thumb drive. You will need a 16 GB USB thumb drive. Wait until extraction has finished. Then open your thumb drive and double click on BT5R3-GNOME-VM-32.vmx to launch BackTrack 5 from your thumb drive. BackTrack will now run as a virtual machine on VMware Workstation.